# Module stopped working when upgrade to 7.x-3.11

Tags: services

I have a API that was working before I did the upgrade. It returns JSON, but after upgrade it only shows:

**Services Endpoint "my_test" has been setup successfully**, and it never gets inside 'access callback' => ‘_my_test_access'...

Can anyone help me please?

My code:

```
function magmanager_services_resources() {  
return array(  

    'my_test' => array(  
        'create' => array(  
            'help' => 'My test',  
            'callback' => '_my_test',  
            'access callback' => ‘_my_test_access',  
            'access arguments' => array('create'),  
            'access arguments append' => TRUE,  
            'args' => array(  
                        array(  
                            'name' => 'pid',  
                            'type' => 'int',  
                            'description' => t('Pid'),  
                            'source' => array('data' => 'pid'),  
                            'optional' => FALSE,  
                        )  
                    )  
            )),  
);  
}  

function _my_test_access() {  

return TRUE;  
}  

function _my_test(){  

$arr = array('a' => '1');  
return json_encode($arr);  
}
```

Testing in command line: $  curl -X POST -v -F "pid=44430"  localhost/api/my_test

> POST /api/my_test HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Length: 143
>   Expect: 100-continue
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------03146779a7db0f80
>
> < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>   < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   < Date: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 18:21:27 GMT
>   * Server Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) is not blacklisted
>   < Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
>   < X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze23
>   < Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
>   < Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 18:21:27 +0000
>   < Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   < ETag: "1422901287"
>   < Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   < Content-Length: 56
>   < Content-Type: text/html
>   <
>   * Connection #0 to host left intact
>   Services Endpoint "my_test" has been setup successfully.